# Why does this jQuery code work in Firefox but not Chrome or Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, webkit

I'm using jQuery to highlight (by changing bg color) some table cells. I want the button (a simple anchor) to be given the class name 'selected' when clicked and I want certain table cells below the buttons to highlight. When you click the same button again, it deselects and removes the highlights from the table cells. When you click a different button, it removes the other highlights and switches to the new appropriate ones.

This all works perfectly in Firefox. When I try it in a webkit browser, it does not. I can't figure out why and it's driving me crazy! The jQuery code is below. You can see the page at:

http://byegurl.com/scores.html

```
$(function(){
$(".press").click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    name = $("." + id);
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) 
         {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            $(name).removeClass('highlight');
         } else {
            $('.press').removeClass('selected');
            $("td:not(name)").removeClass('highlight');         
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(name).addClass('highlight');
         }
    return false; 
});
});
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is that "not (name)" doing what you really mean, or do you want the the style selector you created?

Comment: Also, the variable 'name' is already a jQuery object, but you're later wrapping it as a new jQuery object.

Not part of your question, but you should be caching your jQuery objects. For example, 'var $this = $(this)' declared once at the beginning, and you can use '$this' thereafter. Consider doing the same for any jQuery objects that are created more than once in a given piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that may solve the problem:

`name` is already a jQuery object. Change this line to:

```
name.removeClass('highlight');
```

and

```
name.addClass('highlight');
```

Also, instead of `return false;`, I recommend `event.preventDefault()`, like this:

```
$('.press').click(function(event) {
    // ...
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It was using 'name' that messed me up. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Your first point won't actually make a difference. Your second point is good advice, but not the cause of the problem in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
name = $("." + id);
```

to:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $("." + id);
```

That is, declare the variables with `var` so they have local scope. 
Without `var`, the variables had global scope and were conflicting with something.

It now works in Chrome/Safari: http://jsbin.com/efilok/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `name` is being used by chrome for some other purpose.  If you were to have your `name` variable not a global variable, ie. `var name` instead of just `name` then it would probably work.  Though I would just use a different variable name.